# Is there a desktop tool for delicious.com (aka del.icio.us)?

Tags: software-recommendation, delicious

I'm looking for a tool that would allow me to interface with my delicious bookmarks from within Ubuntu.  I know of the Firefox plugin, but I don't want something in the browser.  I'd also prefer that it have a GUI.  (Though having a CLI in addition would be nice.)

All I've found in the repos are libraries and Scuttle.

Comment: If not view them in a browser, what do you want to do to/with your bookmarks?

Comment: @sparr Of course, I want to view them in the browser, at some point. However, I want to **manage** my bookmarks stored on **delicious.com** without using the browser addons which exist for Firefox and Chrome. I use both browsers often and was hoping to find an external tool to save and access bookmarks on delicious.com

Answer (score 3):

**[Webmarx](http://webmarx.createweb.de/)** is a browser-independent bookmark manager.

[image]

Comment: Interesting tool, but I don't see reference to delicious anywhere on their site.